# How add an transition for sub sidebar?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need you for resolving my problem
I built two sidebar with bootstrap 4.
His is good but without transitions and effects.
When i click the link "Dashboard" for openning the 2nd sidebar, it's open very fast.

I want some awesome effects.
Have you some ideas?
Thanks you a lot

```css
#sidebar1{

    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 400px;
}

#sidebar2{
    background-color: #aaa;
width: 100px; 
height: 400px; 

}

#main{
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-md-3 collapse show bg-default" id="sidebar1">
      <h2>I'm a sidebar 1</h2>
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#sidebar2" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                  Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <span data-feather="file"></span>
                  Orders
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  Products
                </a>
              </li>
              </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class="col-md-3 collapse show" id="sidebar2">
      <h2>I'm a sidebar 2</h2>      
    </nav>
    <main class="col-md-6" id="main">
      <h2>I'm the main content</h2>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my [codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/DiyfO4UqAy)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like shown below

```
#sidebar2 {
  transition: all 1s;
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
}

.collapse:not(.show) {
  display: block !important;
  width: 0 !important;
  height: 0 !important;
  max-width: 0 !important;
  max-height: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Please note that you cannot add transition to display property. So you need to stop display:none and add height:0 and width: 0 to get the same effect for hiding the element with transitions.

```css
#sidebar1 {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 400px;
}

#sidebar2 {
  transition: all 1s;
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
}

.collapse:not(.show) {
  display: block !important;
  width: 0 !important;
  height: 0 !important;
  max-width: 0 !important;
  max-height: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-md-3 collapse show bg-default" id="sidebar1">
      <h2>I'm a sidebar 1</h2>
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#sidebar2" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                  Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <span data-feather="file"></span> Orders
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  Products
                </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class="col-md-3 collapse show" id="sidebar2">
      <h2>I'm a sidebar 2</h2>
    </nav>
    <main class="col-md-6" id="main">
      <h2>I'm the main content</h2>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you. ok, I 'll try to improve it but you always can propose your idea.